# Are there any technical reasons why MongoDB is no longer available as AMI on Amazon EC2 AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

MongoDB used to provide AMI's on for Amazon EC2 AWS.  This no longer seems to be the case ([MongoDB on AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile/ref=dtl_pcp_sold_by/178-2757281-0818135?ie=UTF8&id=c9032c7b-70dd-459f-834f-c1e23cf3d092)).  Here is a previous  [AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00COAAEH8).

MongoDB 3 official [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/) no longer mention deploying preconfigured AMI's either.

Are there any technical reasons for this?

Comment: I presume they didn't want to be responsible for maintaining the AMI images.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; but support is a business decision; and not a technical one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that AMI deployment of MongoDB has been deprecated and replaced by [MMS Automation](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/tutorial/nav/automation/); however it is stated that

> MMS Automation is currently in Beta with a limited initial user group

(so folks at MongoDB, before deprecating one method please try to make sure that replacement is actually available).

That said; it seems that MMS provides quite a few nice features:interface for provisioning machines, configuring MongoDB nodes and clusters, and upgrading your MongoDB deployment.

However it follows a freemium model (8 free servers; 1GB free per replica set; see [details](https://mms.mongodb.com/#pricing)).  Providing only 1GB free for back up (on your own ec2/aws hardware) doesn't seem quite right ...

More details are available at [MMS site](https://mms.mongodb.com/).